# Why won't this VB 6 code open the serial port?

Tags: vb6

```
Dim MSComm1 As MSComm

on error goto cant_open_com1

MSComm1.CommPort = 1
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
MSComm1.DTREnable = True
MSComm1.Handshaking = comRTS
MSComm1.InBufferSize = 12 + 1  ' +1 for the CR
MSComm1.RThreshold = MSComm1.InBufferSize
MSComm1.RTSEnable = True
MSComm1.InputLen = 0 ' read entire input buffer
MSComm1.InputMode = comInputModeText
MSComm1.NullDiscard = True
MSComm1.OutBufferSize = 0 ' not used, we don't write to the serial port
MSComm1.SThreshold = MSComm1.OutBufferSize
'MSComm1.ParityReplace = ?

MSComm1.PortOpen = True
```

Control passes to the on error handler

Comment: And we have to guess what the error message is? (?)

Comment: @Marco Given the posted code, it should be `Object variable or With block variable not set`, for `MSComm1` is `Nothing`.

Comment: I guess it is because you didn't initialize MSComm1, try setting it as NEW msComm.
set MSComm1 = New MSComm (or something like that)

This is using a control for doing it.
I have never used com ports.. Only once but I've used a nice OCX :P
http://www.thaiio.com/prog-cgi/0002_serial.htm

Comment: I'll add code to get the error message. Oops, I'm new to this - do I need to create an MSCOMM1 object, not just declare it? 100% of the example I have found does not.

thanks for the feedback, +1 to both

Comment: I don't know what kind of object is MSComm, in the examples I found it is a control that you can add. However, when you try to use a class, you need to Declare AND Create the object.

If you say that MSComm1 is Nothing, then, you haven't created it yet. 

I don't know enought to give you a correct answer but I think I'm not so wrong

Comment: +1 to both.  I guess you are correct about creating the object. THE examples don't as they create an exe and can drop a component onto it. I can't as I have an Active X DLL, so will have to insatntiate, but ...  MSComm1 = New MSComm  gives "Invalid use of New keyword". Guess I'd better google for it ...

Comment: http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-64957.html gives the answer ... who wants to post an answer & be awarded the question? @GSerg, you were first to pint out that it was not initialized, so I guess that it goes to you...

Comment: Aaaargh!!  It still fails!!! How to display the last error?

Comment: btw, any ideas on .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626540/testing-active-x-dll-runtime-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-no   because I'm basically doing debug by MsgBox here :-*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "control passes to the error handler", did you forget to add an `Exit Sub`?  In your comments, you say you added the New declaration, but you still having a problem?  Well, I just ran this code and it had no trouble opening the port.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim MSComm1 As New MSComm

  On Error GoTo cant_open_com1

  MSComm1.CommPort = 1
  MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
  MSComm1.DTREnable = True
  MSComm1.Handshaking = comRTS
  MSComm1.InBufferSize = 12 + 1
  MSComm1.RThreshold = MSComm1.InBufferSize
  MSComm1.RTSEnable = True
  MSComm1.InputLen = 0
  MSComm1.InputMode = comInputModeText
  MSComm1.NullDiscard = True
  MSComm1.OutBufferSize = 0
  MSComm1.SThreshold = MSComm1.OutBufferSize

  MSComm1.PortOpen = True

  Exit Sub

cant_open_com1:
    Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Note, vb6 won't permit   Dim MSComm1 As New MSComm.  It has to be two statements:   Dim MSComm1    Set MSComm1 = New MSComm   and you *must* include the "Set"

Comment: @mawg: As I said, *I just ran this code and it had no trouble opening the port*.  Did you?  If you did, and it doesn't work for you, well then I guess we have another issue to contend with.  Perhaps you should post a question inquiring as to why it doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Do not set printer on port COM1. COM1 port will be occupied by Printer in COM1 port. When use Visual Basic MSCOMM component, you do not need any printer driver. If you do set Printer in COM1 port. You can use the following code. this code will not impacted by printer setting.

Visual Basic: Open "COM1" For Output AS #1